# Curve UILabel dynamically?

Tags: swift

Is there a way / subclass to create a curved UILabel , and change it's angle dynamically, while keeping all it's properties ? ( like bending it to fit a circle)

The only example I found was to create it once, and it didn't really understood how to put it to work as a regular UILabel with all it's properties :

[Draw text along circular path in Swift for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771864/draw-text-along-circular-path-in-swift-for-ios)

I was looking for something like :

```
let label = UILabel ....
label.font...
label.text...
label.bendAngle ...
```

Comment: Subclass `UILabel` and override `-drawTextInRect:`.

Comment: You can't do that with a `UILabel`. But you can create your own custom view that draws text like that.

Comment: That's the question, so how would I ?

Comment: The second answer in the post you mentioned tells you how to do that. It's an IBDesignable label subclass.

Comment: @Curnelious You linked an answer which does the curved drawing already. Just call out to that function from `-drawTextInRect:`.

Comment: I see. Ok I will investigate. thanks a lot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771864/draw-text-along-circular-path-in-swift-for-ios/32785652#32785652