# circular dial using small small buttons in swift

Tags: ios, swift4

I want to create a circular dial in swift. The entire circle is divided into images and I want to place those images to create a circle. Each image is clickable so that one image placed in centre of the arch could get change.

So I need to create circle using buttons in swift. Please note that I don't want to create a circular button, I want to create circle using button. Something like what is done in below link using labels.

[Draw text along circular path in Swift for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771864/draw-text-along-circular-path-in-swift-for-ios?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have `n` images to arrange around the circumference of a circle of radius `r`. The circle is 2π radians, so use polar coordinates from the center of the circle to find the points on the circumference at angles that are multiples of `2π/n`. Now center the images (buttons) at those points.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i got it what you are saying(r,θ),  but how can i calculate this formula in swift to find the polar coordinates.In the above example same thing is happening but they are using CGContext with just providing the angle and radius.

Comment: I didn't ask for the code from scratch anyway but i got the formula now and my approach too, thanks :)