# How to draw text when using layers in NSView with Swift

Tags: swift, calayer, desktop

I'm using layers in my NSView as much of the display will change infrequently.  This is working fine.  I'm now at the point where I'd like to add text to the layer.  This is not working.

To draw the text, I'm trying to use code from another answer on [how to draw text on a curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771864/draw-text-along-circular-path-in-swift-for-ios/32785652#32785652). I've researched and nothing I've tried helps.  I've created a Playground to demonstrate.  I can see when I run the Playground that the code to display the text is actually called, but nothing is rendered to the screen.  I'm sure I've got something wrong, just not sure what.

The playground is below, along with the code referenced from above (updated for Swift 5, NS* versus UI*, and comments removed for size).

```swift
import AppKit
import PlaygroundSupport

func centreArcPerpendicular(text str: String,
                            context: CGContext,
                            radius r: CGFloat,
                            angle theta: CGFloat,
                            colour c: NSColor,
                            font: NSFont,
                            clockwise: Bool){

   let characters: [String]         = str.map { String($0) }
   let l                            = characters.count
   let attributes                   = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]

   var arcs: [CGFloat] = []
   var totalArc: CGFloat = 0

   for i in 0 ..< l {
      arcs                          += [chordToArc(characters[i].size(withAttributes: attributes).width, radius: r)]
      totalArc                      += arcs[i]
   }

   let direction: CGFloat           = clockwise ? -1 : 1
   let slantCorrection: CGFloat     = clockwise ? -.pi / 2 : .pi / 2

   var thetaI                       = theta - direction * totalArc / 2

   for i in 0 ..< l {
      thetaI                        += direction * arcs[i] / 2
      centre(text: characters[i],
             context: context,
             radius: r,
             angle: thetaI,
             colour: c,
             font: font,
             slantAngle: thetaI + slantCorrection)
      thetaI                        += direction * arcs[i] / 2
   }
}

func chordToArc(_ chord: CGFloat, radius: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
   return 2 * asin(chord / (2 * radius))
}

func centre(text str: String,
            context: CGContext,
            radius r: CGFloat,
            angle theta: CGFloat,
            colour c: NSColor,
            font: NSFont,
            slantAngle: CGFloat) {
   let attributes                   = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: c, NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]
   context.saveGState()
   context.translateBy(x: r * cos(theta), y: -(r * sin(theta)))
   context.rotate(by: -slantAngle)
   let offset                       = str.size(withAttributes: attributes)
   context.translateBy (x: -offset.width / 2, y: -offset.height / 2)
   str.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), withAttributes: attributes)
   context.restoreGState()
}
class CustomView: NSView {
   let textOnCurve                 = TextOnCurve()

   override init(frame: NSRect) {
      super.init(frame: frame)
      wantsLayer                   = true
   }
   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
   }
   override func updateLayer() {
      let textOnCurveLayer          = CAShapeLayer()
      textOnCurveLayer.frame        = self.frame
      textOnCurveLayer.delegate     = textOnCurve
      textOnCurveLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
      layer?.addSublayer(textOnCurveLayer)
   }
}

class TextOnCurve: NSObject, CALayerDelegate {
   func draw(_ layer: CALayer, in ctx: CGContext) {
      ctx.setFillColor(.white)
      ctx.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
      ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 150, y: 100))
      ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 150, y: 150))
      ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 150))
      ctx.closePath()
      ctx.drawPath(using: .fill)

      ctx.translateBy(x: 200.0, y: 200.0)
      centreArcPerpendicular(text: "Anticlockwise",
                             context: ctx,
                             radius: 100,
                             angle: CGFloat(-.pi/2.0),
                             colour: .red,
                             font: NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16),
                             clockwise: false)
      centre(text: "Hello flat world",
             context: ctx,
             radius: 0,
             angle: 0 ,
             colour: .yellow,
             font: NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16),
             slantAngle: .pi / 4)
   }
}


let containerView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView
```

The box is drawn, but the text is not.

If I do not use layers, then I can draw text by calling the methods in the standard `draw:` method.  So the code should work, but, something about the use of layers is preventing it.