# How to curve to label text?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, label, curve

I am making photo editing application and I am stuck with curve functionality for label text. I don't know how to add this functionality. I am searched all most but nothing helped me. I want this type of curved. [Please check this clip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v7epiw7rjdpf354/RPReplay_Final1645182999.mov?dl=0). I have not doing anything on my code because I don't know anything for this type of functionality.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771864/draw-text-along-circular-path-in-swift-for-ios/32785652#32785652

Comment: I checked this but it will not work like that.