# how to make a gauge view with highlight value as in the following image in Swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, swift5, gauge

I have looked at the libraries like gauge kit but they does not solve my problem. Are there any other libraries for making gauge view as in the image? If not, then how can I go around about it?

I Checked these articles and the Libraries

https://medium.com/ajay-bhanushali/create-gaugeview-speedometer-in-swift-571ff97d1a68 (It does not give a label)

Libraries - (GaugeView, ABGaugeViewKit, WMGaugeView, AnyChart for iOS etc) - sectionsGapValue is different in my case

So I am stuck out in between the actual gauge.

[image]

Comment: You probably need to find a pre-made "gauge view" and then modify it to suite your needs.

Answer (score -1):

You should create your custom UIControl (make it IBDesignable). And draw it in

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) { }
```

This tutorial should help you.

Detailed code to draw the text along a circular path, in this SO post : [Draw text along circular path in Swift for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771864/draw-text-along-circular-path-in-swift-for-ios/32785652)

Comment: What is wrong here ? The second link is to show how to draw circular text, not to design the custom control.

Comment: This would be suitable as a *comment* ... review [answer].